# How to send data to another fragment in one activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to send data to another fragment in one activity?

I have two fragment that have been created using Android Studio Design View Editor. I ccreated these two fragment on my MainActivity. fragment1 is the ID of first fragment, it contain just EditText and a button. fragment2 is the ID of second fragment, it just contain textView.

How to send data from EditText of fragment1 to textView of fragment2?

I have write some code below, please check it.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.radioswiba.belajar2buahfragment;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Fragment2.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
//this code was generated by Android Studio
//i have deleted some unused code and comments

package com.example.radioswiba.belajar2buahfragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    //let's define some of variable
    private EditText text_input;
    private Button button_send;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //this generated by Android Studio
    public static Fragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    //this generated by Android Studio
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // my code here
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        text_input = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        button_send = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.post_btn);
        button_send.setOnClickListener(postStatus);
        return rootView;
    }

    View.OnClickListener postStatus = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            text_of_me = text_input.getText().toString();
            //
            //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?
            //SHOULD I USED BUNDLE?


        }
    };

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

**Fragment2.java**

```
//the code almost same with Fragment1.java
```

I have search similar quenstion on stackoverflow, but i can not figure out. I have found many solution like below:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

There we create a new Fragment, meanwhile i have had two fragment on my activity, i have create it manually from file -> new -> new fragment from android Studio Menu. Should i create new Fragment by using above code?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to communicate between fragments and/or activities is with [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), an event bus library.

if you implement it correctly, I am quite confident it gonna solve your issue.

Here is few examples :

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html
https://github.com/CardinalNow/event-bus-example
http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/48752686831/playing-around-with-otto-on-android